# YouTubePlayerSupportFragment Listener doesen't work

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-youtube-api

In my `Fragment` Class the `PlaybackEventListener` and the `PlayerStateChangeListener` don't work. It will not show the Toast.

This is my Code:

**Imports:**

```
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; 
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction; 
import android.util.Log; import android.view.LayoutInflater; 
import android.view.View; import android.view.ViewGroup; 
import android.widget.Toast;    
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer; 
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener; 
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider; 
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment;
```

**Script:**

```
private static final String API_KEY = "-------";
private static String VIDEO_ID = "------";
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.you_tube_api, container, false);

    final YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
    final FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.youtube_layout, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();

    youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(API_KEY, new OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, final YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
            /*Listener*/

            final YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener mPlaybackEventListener = new YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onPaused() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPlaying() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onSeekTo(int arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStopped() {

                }

            };
            final YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener mPlayerStateChangeListener = new YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAdStarted() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoaded(String arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoading() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onVideoEnded() {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"END",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onVideoStarted() {

                }
            };
            player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(mPlayerStateChangeListener);
            player.setPlaybackEventListener(mPlaybackEventListener);
            if (!wasRestored) {
                player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
                player.loadVideo(VIDEO_ID);
                player.play();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult error) {
            String errorMessage = error.toString();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("errorMessage:", errorMessage);
        }

    });
    return rootView;
}
```

Can Somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

you can try with following way:

```
 youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(API_KEY, new OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, final YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
            /*Listener*/

            player.PlaybackEventListener mPlaybackEventListener = new YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onPaused() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPlaying() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onSeekTo(int arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStopped() {

                }

            };
            player.PlayerStateChangeListener mPlayerStateChangeListener = new YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAdStarted() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoaded(String arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoading() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onVideoEnded() {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"END",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onVideoStarted() {

                }
            };

            if (!wasRestored) {
                player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
                player.loadVideo(VIDEO_ID);
                player.play();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult error) {
            String errorMessage = error.toString();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("errorMessage:", errorMessage);
        }

    });
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me...

Inside onInitializationSuccess:

```
                 player.setPlaybackEventListener(

                        new YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onPaused() {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onPlaying() {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onSeekTo(int arg0) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onStopped() {

                            }

                        }



                );


                player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(

                        new YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onAdStarted() {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason arg0) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onLoaded(String arg0) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onLoading() {


                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onVideoEnded() {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onVideoStarted() {

                            }
                        }


                );
```